# Decimal digits in $\pi$

Tags: irrational-numbers, pi

Around ten years ago I had read somewhere that there was a question in an exam for application for software engineer position in a big company which states: "What is the one billionth digit of $\pi$?" Can we predict the $n$th digit of $\pi$ without knowing any preceding digits at all?

Comment: Yes, there are algorithms that compute the $n$th digit without computing all those preceeding digits - though I'm not sure if that works with *decimal* digits (it sure does with binary digits)

Comment: According to Wikipedia, no such way is known. However, it is possible in hexadecimal, using a very impressive formula of one Simon Plouffe.

Comment: We *can* in base $16$ (and hence in other bases of powers of $2$) using the Bailey-Borwein-Plouffe formula, but to my knowledge no such algorithm is known for base $10$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula#BBP_digit-extraction_algorithm_for_.CF.80

Comment: @Travis Nice! Please, write this, along with an example to find the, say, 1536363th digit in hexadecimal representation, so I can accept it.

Comment: very nice results the comments are referring to...but I doubt that this is what the people at the company had in mind when they asked a software engineer about this (unless the company had extremely close relationships to a math department of some university, that is ;-).

Comment: @Thomas Yes, this occurred to me as well. By the way, the company was Google, and the question has been asked in 2001. How should the poor applicant know BBP formula and applying that, establish a formula to find a decimal equivalent?

Comment: I just 'googled' a bit. $\pi$ was calculated to the millionth place the first time in the early 60s of last century using an IBM computer. I'm rather sure each desktop PC you could buy in 2001 would have been able to do the same rather fast, assuming an efficient algorithm were used (like the Machin like formulae https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machin-like_formula). But I would not expect that a Software engineer would know these, either...

Comment: @NimaBavari I feel that my comment doesn't answer the interview question as it presumably refers to the decimal representation of $\pi$. Anyway, I don't think I can add any insight that isn't contained in the link.

Comment: @Thomas Precisely so.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if the recently (January 2022) [posting by Simon Plouffe](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.12601) is correct. He claims a method he discovered can retrieve individual decimal digits of pi without needed any previous digits.

Comment: Welcome to the site.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the family of algorithms called [spigot algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spigot_algorithm), which are designed to do just that: generate digits within the the $b$-ary expansion of irrational constants (for some integer $b>2$).

For your example of $\pi$, the [Bailey-Borwein-Plouffe formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula) gives rise to such a spigot algorithm specifically for $\pi$.